# Filter where date in JSON field - Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

let's see this screenshot:
[image]

I have a "dates" field which is a JSON field, array casted in eloquent model.

So, I want to filter rows older or newer than one of the dates listed in this field. I've tried something like this, but it returns empty collection:

```
$q->where('dates->day', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: have you tried q->whereDate('dates->day', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')); ?

Comment: Your JSON object in `dates` is wrapped in an array. If you are using MySQL then there is no support for greater or less signs when using `JSON_CONTAINS`. If you would use `{"day": "2020-09-21"}` instead of `[ {"day": "2020-09-21"} ]`, you should have the expected results.

Comment: @dbf I can't do this, is an array

Comment: Then you won't solve this problem with SQL using MySQL. Postgre on the other hand is far superior using `jsonb` data types.

Answer (score 0):

Check dates->day format

"dates": {
"day": "2020-12-12"
}

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me (my JSON is not wrapped in an array, though).

```
$query->whereRaw('str_to_date(json_unquote(json_extract(dates, \'$.date\')), \'%Y-%m-%d\') >= str_to_date(\'' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . '\', \'%Y-%m-%d\')');
```